# Remove part of string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

```
var="/ax1121/global/config/domains/adf_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/vmserver1234/"
```

I want the portion "/instances" to be removed and stored in a variable. After removal, it should look as follows

```
var="/ax1121/global/config/domains/adf_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/vmserver1234/"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `bash`:

```
var=${var/\/instances/}
```

This uses the parameter substitution `${variable/pattern/replacement}` to replace (the first) `/instances` string in `$var` with nothing.

This could also be written

```
var=${var/'/instances'/}
```

Comment: And could also be written `var=${var/\/instances}`.If the replacement is empty, the trailing `/` is not required.

Comment: @Isaac Thanks! I'm conditioned by `sed` I guess...

Answer (score 0):

i Have tried with below method using awk comand and worked fine too

command:

```
var=`echo $var|awk '{gsub("/instances","",$0);print $0}'`
```

output

```
echo $var
/ax1121/global/config/domains/adf_domain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/vmserver1234/
```

Comment: The issue here is twofold. Even though the user shows a piece of text including a variable assignment, I believe that it's the text assigned to the variable that they want to change (the value in `$var`), not the text of the script assigning the variable. Also, due to your use of double quotes, the actual pathname is _not_ quoted.

Comment: Ok Thanks for correcting will update the answer

Comment: @Kusalananda Corrected the answer posted it done by awk command